# Problem with DTD error - some xml method does not work

Tags: saml, okta, itfoxtec-identity-saml2

I have error like that :

```
For security reasons DTD is prohibited in this XML document. To enable DTD processing set the DtdProcessing property on XmlReaderSettings to Parse and pass the settings into XmlReader.Create method.
```

this error occurs in this method, could You check ?

```
entityDescriptor.ReadIdPSsoDescriptorFromUrl(new Uri(Configuration["Saml2:IdPMetadata"]));
```

Answer (score 2):

The same error happened to me when I tried to follow the guidance from [Okta](https://developer.okta.com/blog/2020/10/23/how-to-authenticate-with-saml-in-aspnet-core-and-csharp). Later I realized that I used wrong url. Instead of `metadata url`, I have used `Identity Provider Single Sign-On URL`.

At first I tried to load metadata from file with
`entityDescriptor.ReadIdPSsoDescriptorFromFile`. Here I took correct metadata and later I realized the mistake with url.

With Okta the url should look like:

- `https://dev-92799999.okta.com/app/exk59ob18tTqAxxxxx/sso/saml/metadata`

Wrong one I used was:

- `https://dev-92799999.okta.com/app/dev-92785832_oktasamlexample_1/exk59ob18tTqAxxxxx/sso/saml`

Answer (score 1):

I was finally able to find a solution to this problem.  The question originally didn't tag "Okta" or "C#", but I believe this error was encountered when trying to follow the setup instructions here:

https://developer.okta.com/blog/2020/10/23/how-to-authenticate-with-saml-in-aspnet-core-and-csharp

As noted in the article open the SAML Setup Instructions, which can (currently) be found by clicking the "Sign On" tab of your application:

[image: Okta screenshot]

The value you in the "Identity Provider Single Sign-On URL" should look something like this:

```
https://dev-xxxxxxx.okta.com/app/dev-xxxxxx1_testapp_1/exk3--------------/sso/saml
```

Using this URL will result in the DTD error as shown in the question.

To build the correct URL:

1. Remove the URL section between "app" and "exk...".  I think this is the appId, but not sure.
2. Add "/metadata" to the end

So, based on the above example, the final URL will be:

```
`https://dev-xxxxxxx.okta.com/app/exk3--------------/sso/saml/metadata
```

As a quick test, you should be able to hit this URL in a browser.

FWIW, this aligns with mybrave's answer, but with a bit more detail on how to get the correct metadata URL.

Answer (score 0):

It is a security check, apparently the external metadata XML contain DTD (Document Type Definition) which is not allowed.

Comment: is there any solution for that?

Comment: You can download the external metadata and remove the DTD element. It the metadata XML document is signed, then remove the signature. There is really no reason for signing a metadata document. You can do it manually or programmatically.

Comment: Could You tell me where I have to save this document? 
Where is that DTD element to remove? In Your package?

Comment: It is not supported in the ITfoxtec Identity Saml2 package. You need to implement download and XML formatting your selv.

Comment: Make sure the path to your metadata url is correct. You can verify that by navigating to the url in browser and getting back the results containing your metadata.